# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'indexOf') (react-apexcharts)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, apexcharts

So I am working on a personal project and I am using the nextjs with Apexchart. However, everytime I want to render the 7 day historical graph for a specific id, it just breaks and throws this error:

[image: error]

I have two dataset currently.

1. 17, 81, 4, 40, 1, 5, 28, 175, 176, 174, 93, 121, 21, 18, 16, 15 (which works btw)
2. 17, 81, 4, 40, 1, 5, 28, 175, 176, 121, 21, 18, 16, 15, 29 (which breaks)

so I am sure that the issue I am seeing is specifically related to the id 29.

Here is my DashboardGraph component.

```
const MyDashboardHashrateGraph: React.FC<IDashboardHashrateGraphProps> = (
  props
) => {
  const {
    content: { cHeading, cGraphYAxis, cViewFullGraph }
  } = props;
  const theme = useTheme();
  const { minerGroups: mgFiltered } = useContext(DashboardFilterContext);
  const { minerGroups } = useUser();
  const allFilters = [...mgFiltered];

  const MINER_GROUP_IDS =
    minerGroups?.length && minerGroups.map(({ id }) => id);

  const minerGroupResponses = useQueries(
    MINER_GROUP_IDS
      ? MINER_GROUP_IDS.map((id) => ({
          queryKey: ['miner-group-hashrate-history', id],
          queryFn: () => v2Endpoints.getMinerGroupHashrateHistory(id)
        }))
      : []
  );

  const isLoading = minerGroupResponses.filter((pr) => pr.isLoading).length > 0;
  const isSuccess = minerGroupResponses.filter((pr) => pr.isSuccess).length > 0;
  const isError = minerGroupResponses.filter((pr) => pr.isError).length > 0;

  const isReady = !isLoading && !isError && isSuccess;

  let maxYAxis = { pow: 0, unit: '', value: '0' };

  if (isReady) {
    if (allFilters.length > 0) {
      const filteredMinerGroupIds = allFilters.map(
        (minerGroup) => minerGroup.id
      );
      const filterMinerGroupResponses = minerGroupResponses.filter((minerGrp) =>
        filteredMinerGroupIds.includes(minerGrp.data.minerGroupId)
      );

      maxYAxis = transformHashrate(
        Math.max(
          ...filterMinerGroupResponses.map((response) => {
            const pr = response.data as IMinerGroupStatsHistoryResponse;
            return pr?.max;
          })
        )
      );
    } else {
      maxYAxis = transformHashrate(
        Math.max(
          ...minerGroupResponses.map((response) => {
            const pr = response.data as IMinerGroupStatsHistoryResponse;
            return pr?.max;
          })
        )
      );
    }
  }

  // 29, 119
  const mappedminerGroupResponses = isReady
    ? minerGroupResponses
        .filter(
          (res) =>
            res.data.records?.length > 0 &&
            [
              // 17, 81, 4, 40, 1, 5, 28, 175, 176, 174, 93, 121, 21, 18, 16, 15
              17, 81, 4, 40, 1, 5, 28, 175, 176, 121, 21, 18, 16, 15, 29
              // 119
            ].includes(res.data.minerGroupId)
        )
        .map((response) => {
          const poolResponse = response.data as IMinerGroupStatsHistoryResponse;

          return {
            minerGroupId: poolResponse.minerGroupId,
            color: poolResponse?.minerGroupColor,
            min: {
              raw: poolResponse.min,
              pretty: transformHashrate(poolResponse.min, maxYAxis.pow)
            },
            max: {
              raw: poolResponse.max,
              pretty: transformHashrate(poolResponse.max, maxYAxis.pow)
            },
            records: formatGraphData(poolResponse.records, maxYAxis)
          };
        })
    : [];

  const options: ApexOptions = {
    chart: {
      id: 'dashboardHashrateGraph',
      type: 'line',
      toolbar: {
        show: false
      },
      zoom: {
        enabled: false
      },
      animations: {
        enabled: false
      }
    },
    xaxis: {
      type: 'datetime',
      labels: {
        datetimeUTC: false
      }
    },
    yaxis: {
      min: 0,
      max: Number(maxYAxis?.value) * 1.0004,
      title: {
        text: `${cGraphYAxis} (${maxYAxis.unit})`
      }
    },
    tooltip: {
      x: {
        format: 'MMM dd, HH:mm'
      },
      y: {
        formatter: (val) => `${val} ${maxYAxis.unit}`,
        title: {
          formatter: (val) => val
        }
      }
    },
    legend: {
      offsetY: 5,
      onItemClick: {
        toggleDataSeries: false
      }
    }
  };

  const mergedOptions = defaultGraphOptions(theme, options);

  const series = isReady
    ? mappedminerGroupResponses.map((poolResponse) => {
        // Find the timestamp of 7 days ago at the closest 5-minute interval
        const interval = 5 * 60 * 1000; // 5 minutes in milliseconds
        const currentDate = new Date();
        const sevenDaysAgo = new Date(
          currentDate.getTime() - 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000
        );
        const startTimestamp =
          Math.ceil(sevenDaysAgo.getTime() / interval) * interval;

        // Fill the array with missing timestamps
        let currentTimestamp = startTimestamp;

        while (currentTimestamp < currentDate.getTime()) {
          const isTimestampPresent = poolResponse?.records.some(
            ([timestamp]) => timestamp === currentTimestamp
          );
          if (!isTimestampPresent) {
            const timestampArray = [currentTimestamp, '0'];
            poolResponse?.records.push(timestampArray);
          }
          currentTimestamp += interval;
        }

        // Sort the array by timestamp in ascending order
        poolResponse?.records.sort((a, b) => a[0] - b[0]);

        return {
          name: minerGroups.filter(
            (mg) => mg.id === poolResponse.minerGroupId
          )[0].name,
          ...(poolResponse?.color && { color: poolResponse?.color }),
          data: poolResponse?.records || []
        };
      })
    : [{ name: 'loading...', data: [] }];

  console.log(series);
  useEffect(() => {
    if (isReady && typeof ApexCharts !== 'undefined') {
      if (allFilters.length) {
        series.forEach((pool) => {
          // eslint-disable-next-line no-shadow
          if (allFilters.some((filter) => filter.name === pool.name)) {
            ApexCharts.exec('dashboardHashrateGraph', 'showSeries', pool.name);
          } else {
            ApexCharts.exec('dashboardHashrateGraph', 'hideSeries', pool.name);
          }
        });
      } else {
        series.forEach((pool) => {
          ApexCharts.exec('dashboardHashrateGraph', 'showSeries', pool.name);
        });
      }
    }
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, [allFilters, isReady]);

  return (
    <ModuleWrapper
      heading={cHeading}
      testId="pool-hashrate"
      headingTopRight={{
        text: cViewFullGraph,
        link: '/mine-management/report'
      }}
    >
      {allFilters.length ? <FilterPills filterItems={allFilters} /> : <></>}
      <DashboardHashrateChart
        options={mergedOptions}
        series={series}
        type="line"
        width="100%"
        height={250}
      />
    </ModuleWrapper>
  );
};

export default MyDashboardHashrateGraph;
```

I have a feeling that id 29 is missing some data, but I am not sure about that. If I console.log series, I get the same number of dataset for all ids, i did looked into each dataset associated with the id and made sure that the data for x axis is same.

Here is the sample for `series` variable:-

[image: series variale]

[image: expanded dataset]

If I remove id 29 from the dataset, the graph would render fine as shown in the image below:-

[image]

Now I am not sure what's causing this error to come up! Could it be the missing data, if so, how can I "pre-fill" the missing data and show it on the graph on x axis using react-apexchart?

Thanks in advance and if anyone needs any extra information, feel free to add a comment.

I tried looking at the apexchart documentation with missing/null values but that didn't helped as well. I tried 'pre-filling' dataset with the expectation of that its just the missing data which is causing the error to come up but I was wrong!

ID 29 should be displayed on the graph like this one:-

[image]